# Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle

Tags: java, jsp

Any ideas on what this below error is???
 `JSP Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key el.convert` i am getting this when using a jsp. Am i missing some thing??

```
 <c:set var="count" value="0" scope="page" />

                      <c:forEach items="${usersList}" var="userNames" >
                      <c:set var="counter" value="${count + 1}" scope="page"/>
                      <li class="msImages">
                      <c:choose>
                      <c:when test="${counter lt '4'}">
                          <p> <span> I am creating an image</span>

                           </p>
                         </c:when>
                        <c:when test="${counter eq '4'}">
                                  <span>See More </span>
                                  </c:when>

                         </c:choose>

  </li>
```

Comment: Show us the code that causes the problem. We're not psychic (most of the time).

Comment: It might help if you show your JSP?!

Comment: @Matt Ball i have edited the question

Comment: @Matt Ball i found the issue i ve to remove this `varStatus="count"` right??

Comment: @MattBall Is my looping correct now?? I ve edited the code.. I am getting some repeated image generation..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the same variable name `count` twice. Remove the `<c:set var="count" value="0" scope="page" />`. Also, you should use *properties* of the `varStatus`, and not the value directly. [It's not a primitive object.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0318/#N102E5)

```
<c:forEach items="${usersList}" var="userNames" varStatus="stat">
    <c:set var="counter" value="${stat.count + 1}" scope="page"/>
    <li class="msImages">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${counter lt 4}">
                <p> <span> I am creating an image</span> </p>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${counter eq 4}">
                <span>See More </span>
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```